# PWM-driven MOSFET heats up

Tags: mosfet, pwm, temperature

I have designed an MCU-based PWM dimmer for LED strips.

My circuit works fine but there is a problem: The MOSFET is unexpectedly hot (i.e. 65°C). So I scoped the drain voltage using an oscilloscope and I saw that the drain voltage was about 0.130V (as expected) when the MOSFET is on, but it is 9V --it should be 16V-- when the MOSFET is off. So I'm not sure but I think that this causes the MOSFET to heat up.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTzMXS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where is my fault? How can I solve this problem?

EDIT: Here are the waveform of V<sub>DS</sub>:

[image]

[image]

Comment: "So I scoped the drain voltage using an oscilloscope " no pictures it did not happen

Comment: Looks like Q1 isn't turning fully on. What's the voltage across R6 As a start, try removing Q1 and R5, then wire-link the Q1 base pad to the R5 pad that goes to R6. Then look at the FET voltages again.

Comment: I'd also be adding a flyback diode to this one... That's likely a good whack of inductance with 20 of those LED strings in parallel.

Comment: What current are those 20 strings running at? What sort of heatsinking have you put on the FET?

Comment: Are you definitely driving the circuit with 500 Hz PWM, not lots of kHz?

Comment: You need to get together with this guy and combine your driver stages... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/351842/transistor-push-pull-stage-to-drive-mosfet#351842

Comment: Check the actual circuit against your circuit diagram - are R4-R6 on the board the same as declared on the circuit? Maybe R5 actually installed is 1.6K, and not 16R?

Comment: "but it is 9V --it should be 16V" - no, it shouldn't. Your scope input has resistance which draws current though the LEDs to ground, and the FET has leakage current when turned off. Some 5mm white LEDs that I tested had a voltage drop of 2.2V each at 0.25uA. 20 parallel x 3 in series would drop 6.6V at 5uA. The AOD444 has maximum leakage current of 5uA at 55ºC. A 1 Meg scope input draws 9uA at 9V.

Comment: With three LEDs and a 10-ohm resistor, you're putting something on the order of half an amp through each string, and 20 strings in parallel will be putting 10 amps through the MOSFET. That's 1.3W of dissipation -- do you have a heatsink on it?

Comment: @DaveTweed hard to tell that for sure.. at 0.13V @ 50mR it's only ~0.3W... still.. it's gonna be warm. We are missing a few numbers here.. but 40C rise does not seem unreasonable.

Comment: Wooz, why haven't you responded to any of these comments or answers? Also, why not put something around \$10\:\text{k}\Omega\$ to \$47\:\text{k}\Omega\$ from drain to (+) of your supply rail and measure again to see if that \$9\:\text{V}\$ measurement persists?

Comment: @jonk that seems to be the way these days... ask a question... come back tomorrow and see if there is an answer... It's a millennial thing.... text based comms....

Comment: @Trevor_G: It's strange that you'd consider *not* constantly being online and expecting an immediate response to a question to be "a millennial thing". I still remember the time when posting a question on a public forum would involve mailing a physical letter to a publisher and waiting to see if they'd print it. And then waiting to see if anyone would reply. And based on your profile, you're older than I am.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I'm just rationalizing, and yes I remember those days too.

Comment: What is the duty cycle (%) for the PWM signal?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Different situations, completely. I was using UUCP over POTS prior to UUNET's arrival and was one of the first to jump to UUNET when it arrived circa 1987. I was also an early adopter of NNTP. So I very much remember the days when one might wait days or weeks. But this site's questions are "stale" by the time a day's gone by and a questioner should stick around for at least 30 minutes, I think, to help elaborate on the question a bit, as needed. It is basic courtesy and demonstrates a care for the time of others you hope will help out. So different situations.

Comment: Zoom in. How long is the fall time? Also show the rise time.

Comment: @Trevor_G I uploaded oscilloscope images.

Comment: @TonyM thanks for interest I tried your suggestion but nothing changed. Yes I am driving 500Hz 50% duty cycle PWM.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Yes it is quite reasonable.

Comment: @wooz Also show the gate voltage.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thanks for your thought. There is about 8 hours of time difference between here and U.S. We humans have a need of sleeping.:)

Comment: @wooz as I suspected, you need a fly-back diode to get rid of those spikes when it turns off.

Comment: Continued: It also looks like there is some ringing on that turn off too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 9 volts is a red herring. 0.13 volts across a FET of on-resistance of 0.05 ohms is a power of 340 mW and this will generate heat. The junction to ambient thermal resistance is typically 50 K/W, so without a heat sink and at a local ambient temperature of 30 °C, the temperature will rise to 30 °C + 0.34 W * 50 K/W = 47 °C then factor in that the temperature rise might locally increase ambient another twenty degrees and you are at 67 °C. Not really a problem.

Comment: It comes from the leakage current of the MOSFET. This leakage current causes about 2 volt drop across each LED. And yes, the numbers don't lie; 40°C of temperature rise is very logical according to calculations.

Answer (score 4):

Actually 65C, a 40C rise is not really out of the question with this circuit.

Assuming your numbers are right, a \$50m\Omega\$ on resistance with 0.13V that's 1/3W already. At 60C/W that's a 20C rise if it is turned on all the time.

Add in the switching losses and other errors it does not take much to get up to 2/3W. Improving the turn off time would help a little.

As Bruce Abbott mentioned in the comments, the 9V thing may be a "[red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring)" here.

Also, as I mentioned in a comment, I'd also be adding a fly-back diode to this circuit... That's likely a good whack of inductance with 20 of those LED strings in parallel.

Comment: Your argument about high inductance due to parallel LED strings sounds wrong. Inductances in parallel are just like resistors in parallel. Total inductance is L/20, not 20*L.

Comment: @DaveP yes indeed, I just meant it sounds like he has a lot of wiring. Diodes are cheap..